# Incompatible metric (total_interactions) with the media

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to request Instagram media insights. I'm trying to request the metric *total_interactions*, for media where media_product_type='FEED' and media_type='VIDEO'. I was previously requesting the metric *engagement*, but switched to *total_interactions*, according to the API [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/changelog).

The switch is mandatory as using *engagement* no longer works and results in the following error (even when using versions < v18):

> { "error": { "message": "(#100) This metric engagement is no longer
> supported on version v18+. For a list of alternative metrics, visit
> [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights."](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media/insights.%22),
> "type": "OAuthException", "code": 100, "fbtrace_id": "-" } }

However, I receive the following error when requesting "total_interactions":

> { "error": { "message": "(#100) Incompatible metric
> (total_interactions) with the media", "type": "OAuthException",
> "code": 100, "fbtrace_id": "-" } }

The  request is the following:

```
curl -i -X GET 
"https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/<media id sanitized>/insights?metric=total_interactions&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
```

Is anyone able to get the *total_interactions* metric for feed video insights? I can't tell if there's something I'm doing wrong on my end, or if this is a Facebook bug.

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't :') Sadly I assumed it's a Graph API bug and removed the metric from requests where media_product_type='FEED' and media_type='VIDEO'. Still hoping someone may have a better outcome..